# Unexpected error while RSAGA raster calculations

Tags: raster, r, error, saga, topographic-wetness-index

I want to use RSAGA package in R to calculate the topographical wetness index. However, while applying the `rsaga.wetness.index()` function, R gives me an error message (see below).

My question is, where should I look for the problem. In the DEM, perhaps in the installation files of the package?

The input raster is originally saved as `.grd` file, it is of LAEA Europe projection and it has 100 per 100 m resolution.

```
projection(dem)
> "+proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs"

res(dem)
> [1] 100 100

SagaEnv = rsaga.env(modules = 'C:\\SAGA-GIS')
rsaga.wetness.index(in.dem = dem, sagaEnv = SagaEnv)
> Error in nchar(filename) : 
>     no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS StackExchange! I think `in.dem` requires a file path to the `.sgrd` file (input dem).

Answer (score 0):

Save your DEM to a .sgrd file using `writeRaster`:

```
> writeRaster(rdem,"rdem.sgrd", overwrite=TRUE)
```

and then it gets past that error. Of course I have other errors but I'm not using this at the moment. This might work for you. If you get these errors then its a RSAGA version mismatch (I need to upgrade things) and ask a new Q if you can't fix it:

```
> rwi = rsaga.wetness.index("rdem.sgrd","rwi.sgrd")
Error: select a tool
Error in if (any(modules[, wh] == module)) return(TRUE) : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: There were 23 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```